# Python to open the terminal and play a movie through VLC?

Tags: python, vlc

Is it possible to send a command from one Raspberry Pi, to another, and open up a video file with VLC, using Python?

This is my idea that involves this:

Raspberry Pi 1, has a web server on, where user can select what movie they would like to watch  - This is using Python and web.py -> Command is sent to Raspberry Pi 2 -> Plays movie through VLC.

I know to use Paramiko to use SSH between the 2 RPi's, but **what command can I use to open up a video file with VLC?**

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your question exactly what you are asking. Why involve 2 Pis?

IN any event `VLC` will be very slow - try the command line viewer `omxplayer` which uses the GPU, and is included in Rabpbian.